# How to put a CTE as a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

In SQL Server, I have a CTE and a select statement.

The CTE looks like

```
WITH Recursion AS (
    SELECT Value, GroupID, Type
    FROM @GroupMembership
    WHERE GroupID = @requestingGroupID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT M.Value, M.GroupID, M.Type
    FROM Recursion AS R
    INNER JOIN @GroupMembership AS M ON R.Value = M.GroupID AND R.Type = 'Group'
)
SELECT * FROM Recursion
```

and the select statement is this

```
select * 
from [Right] r
inner join Group on r.groupid = Group.id 
inner join (
  -- CTE but @requestingGroupID should be Group.id
) C on C.GroupID = Group.id
```

I want to nest the CTE inside the brackets, but the `@requestingGroupID` from the CTE should be referencing `Group.id` from outside the bracket.

When I try to do this, I get syntax errors. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the attempt you made that creates the syntax error(s). Sample data and expected results will help us too.

Comment: If you provide the DDL+DML to create all that either inline or as a DBFiddle you make it much easier for us to assist.

Comment: Perhaps migrate your CTE into a Table-Valued Function and call it via a CROSS APPLY

Comment: You want a CTE to work as a lateral table expression. Unfortunately they cannot work in that location. The query can be worked out, but it'll need to be heavily rephrased.

Comment: You can't convert a recursive CTE into a subquery (aka derived table)

Comment: It can be done with a function. Eg https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2552487907c0a5304839a5c81cc4d2bb Alternatively you can push the main `select` into the recursion. Eg https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=221b8e27baecbab633e4e4b06bdabbd7

Comment: @Charlieface You'll just need one more vote.     Your dbFiddle is exactly what I was thinking.   OP seemed rather unresponsive

Comment: @Charlieface if OP was engaging and provided some sample data and desired results I'd consider it. I think they have enough rep to not need their hand held.

Answer (score 1):

Without sample data and expected results, it's hard to give a definitive answer.

But basically, you cannot use a recursive CTE as an `APPLY` (where you push outer references in).

The only way to do this is to put the recursive part into an inline Table Valued Function, then `APPLY` it to the rest of the query

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION GetDescendants (@requestingGroupID int)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
WITH Recursion AS (
    SELECT Value, GroupID, Type
    FROM GroupMembership
    WHERE GroupID = @requestingGroupID
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT M.Value, M.GroupID, M.Type
    FROM Recursion AS R
    INNER JOIN GroupMembership AS M ON R.Value = M.GroupID AND R.Type = 'Group'
)
SELECT *
FROM Recursion;
```

```sql
select * 
from [Right] r
inner join Group g on r.groupid = g.id 
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetDescendant ( g.id) C
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2552487907c0a5304839a5c81cc4d2bb)

Alternatively, you can re-arrange your query so that the main `SELECT` is in the anchor part (first part) of the recursion. Admittedly this is not always possible.

```sql
WITH Recursion AS (
    SELECT r.Id, Value, GroupID, Type
    FROM [Right] r
    inner join Group g on r.groupid = g.id 
    JOIN @GroupMembership gm ON gm.GroupID = g.GroupID
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT R.Id, M.Value, M.GroupID, M.Type
    FROM Recursion AS R
    INNER JOIN @GroupMembership AS M ON R.Value = M.GroupID AND R.Type = 'Group'
)
SELECT *
FROM Recursion
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=221b8e27baecbab633e4e4b06bdabbd7)